# Running any version of OS X on a PC

Tags: windows, vpn, mac, virtualization

A common problem for a lot of people I would think, I need to run OS X on my Windows PC virtually because I need to use the VPN client 'Apple Connect' that is only supported on Macs. It does not really matter which version it is from the last sort of 5-6 years.

I have access to;

```
VMWorkstation
VMPlayer
Virtual Box

Mac OSX Lion
Mac OSX Mini
Mac OSX Server Leopard
```

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this, I have seen some instructions on YouTube and various websites but it does not work properly. Does anyone have a package way of doing this.

Tried on different hardware with more RAM and still cannot get it to work.

Comment: You can simple dowonload a Virtual Machine with the OS preinstalled, technically you can do it with VMWare player but is not llegal due the EULA of OSX.

Answer (score 5):

The EULA for OSX precludes it's use on any non Apple platform. You cannot legally do this.

Comment: +1 layman translation "It's illegal to run OSX on anything but Apple hardware"